# best practice to pass mock data to Angular & Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic phone app using AngualrJs as the framework. Now I faced an issue. I don't want my app to send an HTTP request to my backend(which use Ruby on Rails) API to do a manual test.

So I'm wondering what's the best practice to pass a mock JSON data as a response when I want to call the API.

I'm not familiar with Angular and Ionic, I can find some tutorials on both sides but I don't know what's is the best practice if use them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store the data in `localStorage` after the first hit and read the data from `localStorage` every-time whenever you need.

> https://medium.com/@petehouston/awesome-local-storage-for-ionic-with-ngstorage-c11c0284d658

Or you can use 
`$httpBackend`

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

by saving json files locally and injecting them back when the application tries to hit the network . One limitation here, you cannot update the json file later after the user have installed the application.

So, `localStorage` is preferred if you want to cache the data you have received from network.